# NodeJs Bull for Background tasks

Tags: node.js, cron, background, cron-task, background-task

I have been using Bull for background tasks in my node application.

https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull

Now that node is single threaded by nature. Does bull use the same thread on which node application is running or it forks another thread and runs as a separate instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From bull quick guide:

> The process function **can also be run<sup>1</sup>** in a separate process. This has
>   several advantages:
>
> - The process is sandboxed so if it crashes it does not affect the
>     worker.
> - You can run blocking code without affecting the queue (jobs
>     will not stall).
> - Much better utilization of multi-core CPUs.
> - Less connections to redis.

In order to use this feature just create a separate file with the processor:

```
// processor.js
module.exports = function(job){
  // Do some heavy work

  return Promise.resolve(result);
}
```

And define the processor like this:

```
// Single process:
queue.process('/path/to/my/processor.js');

// You can use concurrency as well:
queue.process(5, '/path/to/my/processor.js');

// and named processors:
queue.process('my processor', 5, '/path/to/my/processor.js');
```

1. This indicates, naturally bull doesn't create separate process for execution.

Basic guides: https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#separate-processes

Answer (score 0):

No, It will not run in worker thread it will run in main thread so it is recommended not to use blocking code in job.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).